# using word in c# why always show 'save as' dialog when close

Tags: c#, ms-word, save-as

I'm working on some code which trying to convert a Word document to a swf file.

I do it this way:

1. I convert the word document to PDF document by using the office component sevice
2. I convert the PDF to swf by using swftools.

I did it on my computer (64-bit, Windows Server 2008 R2, Office 2010) and it works fine, but when I put it in server (64-bit, Windows server 2008 R2, Office2010), a 'Save As' dialog will show when the code is trying to close Word in program, and whether I click 'save' or 'cancel', it will throw the exception 'the file is readonly'. But actually, I didn't change the original file, I just opened it and saves it as a PDF document.

Here is the code 'convert Word to PDF':

```
bool ret = true;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application newApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = null;
        object Unknown = Type.Missing;
        try
        {

            object Source = path;
            object Target = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf(".")) + ".pdf";
            if (outpath != "")
                Target = outpath;
            object readOnly = true;
            object format = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;
            doc = newApp.Documents.Open(ref Source, ref Unknown, ref readOnly,
                ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown);
            doc.SaveAs(ref Target, ref format,
                ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ret = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (doc != null)
            {
                doc.Close(ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown);
                //dialog shows up here
            }
            newApp.Quit(ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown);
            GC.Collect();
        }

        return ret;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try to remove the swf logic, and just convert the word document to pdf to isolate the problem. If this works on your production server, then this means there is something going on with swftools on the production

Comment: i already did that,the swftools works fine because i try to convert pdf to swf and it works fine in server

Comment: not sure this would make a difference but try `object Unkown=System.Reflection.Missing.Value` rather than what you have now..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass false as the first argument and the prompt will go away

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.close(v=vs.80).aspx